# Creating an oracle database connection with Talend Open Studio

Tags: oracle, talend

I want to create a database connection with talend open studio. I have installed oracle 10g and sqlplus environnement.

When I have tried creating a connection, I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

  at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.JDBCDriverLoader.getConnection(JDBCDriverLoader.java:164)
  at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.ExtractMetaDataUtils.connect(ExtractMetaDataUtils.java:1049)
  at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.ExtractMetaDataFromDataBase.testConnection(ExtractMetaDataFromDataBase.java:311)
  at org.talend.repository.ui.utils.ManagerConnection.check(ManagerConnection.java:266)
  at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.database.DatabaseForm.checkConnection(DatabaseForm.java:2294)
  at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.database.DatabaseForm.access$45(DatabaseForm.java:2217)
  at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.database.DatabaseForm$26.widgetSelected(DatabaseForm.java:2549)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
  at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    ....
```

Here is my login and password:
[image: here is my login and password]

---

this is the tnsnames.ora's content

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCL =
     (DESCRIPTION =
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = user)(PORT = 1521))
          (CONNECT_DATA =
             (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
                )
           )

      EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
       (DESCRIPTION =
         (ADDRESS_LIST =
             (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
         )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SID = PLSExtProc)
            (PRESENTATION = RO)
        )
    )
```

Comment: Are you able to connect from SQLPLUS. Can you please post the contents of your tnsnames.ora.

Comment: @Pika , Have you confirmed if running Oracle instance SID is xe? May be it is XE. (On Linux/Unix SID is case sensitive)

Comment: @phonetic_man Yes I can directly connect to SQLPLUS  with my login and my password.Where can I find this file(tnsnames.ora) ?

Comment: @ShubhangiPardeshi No I have not checked it. I don't know how can I find the SID  of the Oracle instance.I thought that XE is the SID by default.

Comment: @phonetic_man I have just edited the original post .

Comment: @Pika can you run the following command on SQLPLUS SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') FROM DUAL; and try the SID returned by the query.